# How to authenticate and browse to another URL with python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using [Python Selenium Chrome WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
```

and

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
print self.driver.get('https://192.168.178.20:1337/login?email=me@domain.com&password=mypassword')
print self.driver.get('https://192.168.178.20:1337/this/that?name=john')
```

Before I didn't need to authenticate and my `GET` went through, but now I do using `PUT` request with `email` and `password` params. I have tested the `PUT` in POSTMAN and it worked fine.

Once authenticated, I want to browse to another URL using `GET`, but I am getting a `500` most likely because it didn't retain that I have authenticated.

1. How can I check that my login worked? How do I retrieve the response?
2. Do I need to retrieve & save some kind of token or cookie for the 2nd request go through?

## Console log

```
headless_chrome > Auth
None
headless_chrome > GET
None
headless_chrome > CONSOLE
headless_chrome console > {u'source': u'network', u'message': u'https://192.168.178.20:1337/this/that?name=john 0:0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)', u'timestamp': 1479212713208, u'level': u'SEVERE'}
headless_chrome > title:
{'_file_detector': <selenium.webdriver.remote.file_detector.LocalFileDetector object at 0x7f8507a25f50>,
 '_is_remote': False,
 '_mobile': <selenium.webdriver.remote.mobile.Mobile object at 0x7f8507a25d90>,
 '_switch_to': <selenium.webdriver.remote.switch_to.SwitchTo instance at 0x7f8507a336c8>,
 'capabilities': {u'acceptSslCerts': True,
                  u'applicationCacheEnabled': False,
                  u'browserConnectionEnabled': False,
                  u'browserName': u'chrome',
                  u'chrome': {u'chromedriverVersion': u'2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a)',
                              u'userDataDir': u'/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ybR9Fm'},
                  u'cssSelectorsEnabled': True,
                  u'databaseEnabled': False,
                  u'handlesAlerts': True,
                  u'hasTouchScreen': False,
                  u'javascriptEnabled': True,
                  u'locationContextEnabled': True,
                  u'mobileEmulationEnabled': False,
                  u'nativeEvents': True,
                  u'platform': u'Linux',
                  u'rotatable': False,
                  u'takesHeapSnapshot': True,
                  u'takesScreenshot': True,
                  u'version': u'50.0.2661.102',
                  u'webStorageEnabled': True},
 'command_executor': <selenium.webdriver.chrome.remote_connection.ChromeRemoteConnection object at 0x7f8507a25cd0>,
 'error_handler': <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f8507a25d50>,
 'service': <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f85083bc3d0>,
 'session_id': u'72a5ce48d950be26b3f33de4adb34428',
 'w3c': False}
headless_chrome > except else
clean up Selenium browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver has no `.put` method. You should use `.get` for both authentication and then navigating to another url. Ideally this should work.
If that works manually then it should work through webdriver also.

Comment: I am pretty sure I also tried with `.get` and also got the `500`. Will try harder in a bit. Funny that I didn't a `no method error` with `.put`. Is there a way to output the response to the console?

Comment: Take a loot at the `driver.get_log('browser')` method